# Why can the Taylor formula be used to evaluate the limit,Why does its remainder converge to zero？

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

A simple example $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x^2}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^2)-1}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{2}$

---

If taken out alone, its limit is zero.How can I judge that the sum of infinite limits converges to zero.

Such as:$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{o(x^2)}{x^2}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}[\sum\limits_{i=3}^{n} (\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x^i}{x^2})]=?$

Clarification of the problem

For example $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+.....+\frac{1}{n})=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n*\frac{1}{n}=1$

In the case of an infinite number of items,I cannot simply think of adding an infinite number of zero

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean, but the **definition** of “little oh” notation is that $o(x^2)$ means something such that $o(x^2)/x^2 \to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how exact you need it. You could use the remainder term of the Taylor expansion of degree $n$ of some $f$ around some $x_0$ in its more detailed form, $$r_n(x)=\frac{(x-x_0)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}f^{(n+1)}(\xi),~~~\xi\in[x_0,x].$$

For the cosine with $x_0=0$ this would give for example
$$
r_3(x)=\frac{x^4}{4!}\cos(\xi)
$$

Or you could refer back to more elementary means and notice that the cosine series is alternating with falling terms if $x$ is small enough, so that the series is bounded by its partial sums,
$$
1-\frac{x^2}2\le\cos(x)\le 1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{4!}
$$
All this is showing that the defect in the limit formula is smaller than $\frac{x^2}{24}$ which does indeed converge to zero.

Comment: I think I have to take a note, it's great.I haven't thought about these methods,I always think:The coefficient behind the Taylor polynomial is much higher than 2. But I fell into the idea,But I’m not sure if the addition of countless zeros is equal to zero,Because the limit consolidation can only be in a limited project.I never thought about Taylor's remainder, which avoids the trouble of endless projects.

Comment: If you have a power series with radius of convergence $r$, then you know that for example $$|a_n|(2r/3)^n$$ is a bounded sequence, call the bound $A$. Then for $$|x|<r/3$$ you get a remainder formula $$\sum_{k>n}|a_kx^k|\le (3|x|/r)^{n+1}\sum_{k>n}|a_k|(2r/3)^k·(1/2)^{k-n-1}\le 2A·(3|x|/r)^{n+1}.$$ So as long as you stay a little away from the boundary of the convergence region, power series are really well-behaved. Which is one reason for the strong results in complex analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the rules of asymptotic analysis:
$$\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^2)-1}{x^2}=-\frac 12+o(1).$$

*Added*: an elementary way to determine the limit:
$$\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}=\frac{\cos^2 x-1}{x^2(\cos x +1)}=-\underbrace{\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}}_{\substack{\downarrow\\1^2=1}}\,\underbrace{\frac1{\cos x+1}}_{\substack{\downarrow\\1+1=2}}$$